# React Redux: Connected child component not receiving props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I have a component called `DisplayItems` that gets some data from an API (a list of items).

I am using Redux actions and thunk middleware to get the items and data from the API. I save the items and other data to the redux store as an array of objects, and I name it `entriesData`. The actual array is in `entriesData.data`. I am using connect to connect the state and actions to `DisplayItems`' props.

Next, I have a child component called `GalleryItemContentV1`. `GalleryItemContentV1` isn't connected to redux. It just receives the data from `DisplayItems` which loops through the array of items and passes each one to `GalleryItemContentV1`. So, again, `DisplayItems` loops through `this.props.entriesData.data` and passes each item to `GalleryItemContentV1` as a prop called `entry`.

Finally, I have a child component in `GalleryItemContentV1` called `TestCom`. That's where the issue is. I am also passing the item that I got from `DisplyItem` to `TestCom`. So, the data flow is `DisplayItems` (connected) > `GalleryItemContentV1` (not connected) > `TestCom` (connected).

`TestCom` is connected to redux. It uses some actions from redux to update an item in `entriesData.data`. When I update `this.props.entriesData.data` in `TestCom`, `GalleryItemContentV1` receives the updated data just fine, but `TestCom` doesn't receive anything. The item in `TestCom` is never updated.

I figured out that the issue is when I connect `TestCom` to redux. If `TestCom` is not connected to redux, it also receives the updated props, just like `GalleryItemContentV1`.

The components are below. I've tried to simplify them as much as possible.

DisplayItems

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import GalleryItemContentV1 from './GalleryItemContentV1';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {getContestEntriesPageData} from '../../actions/contest';

class DisplayItems extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getContestEntriesPageData(uri, search);
  }

  render(){

    console.log('DisplayItems props', this.props);

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="card-deck thumbnails" id="card-list">
            {  this.props.entriesData.data instanceof Array ? 
                  this.props.entriesData.data.map(function(object, i){
                    return <GalleryItemContentV1 
                      entry={object} key={i} 
                      arr_key={i}
                    />;
                  }, this) : ''
              }
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    entriesData: state.entriesData,
  }
)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getContestEntriesPageData: (uri, search) => {
      dispatch(getContestEntriesPageData(uri, search));
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DisplayItems);
```

GalleryItemContentV1

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TestCom from './TestCom';

class GalleryItemContentV1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <TestCom entry={this.props.entry} />
      </div>
    );
    }
}
export default GalleryItemContentV1;
```

TestCom

I am outputting the results of `this.props.entry.VotesCount` (the item from `DisplayItems`) in `TestCom`. That's where the issue occurs. For some reason, when I connect `TestCom` to redux, its props aren't updated, but when it's disconnected from Redux, then its props are updated.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TestCom extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
  }

  render(){

    console.log('TestCom props', this.props);

    return (

      <div>{this.props.entry.VotesCount}</div>

    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    user: state.user
  }
)
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestCom);
```

Here's where I'm configuring redux, but I don't think it's relevant to know since `GalleryItemContentV1` is seeing the updated data just fine.

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ContestReducer from '../reducers/contest';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    ContestReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
}
```

So, to summarize.

**DisplayItems** (is connected, receives updated data from store okay) > **GalleryItemContentV1** (is not connected, receives updates okay) > **TestCom** (is connected, does not receive updates, but receives updates if disconnected)

Here's my reducer, just in case it helps.

```
import * as ContestActionTypes from '../actiontypes/contest';

const initialState = {
  contest: null,
  subscriptions: [],
  user: null,
  page: null
}
export default function Contest(state=initialState, action) {
  console.log('redux action reducer: ', action)
  switch(action.type) {
    case ContestActionTypes.HANDLE_VOTE:
      const newState = { ...state };
      if (newState.entriesData) {
        const index = newState.entriesData.data.findIndex(x => x.id === action.entry.id)
        newState.entriesData.data[index].VotesCount = action.vote;
      } else {
        newState.entry.VotesCount = action.vote;
      }

      return newState

      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

I also noticed the same thing happening with `GalleryItemContentV1`. If I connect it, then it stops receiving updates from DisplayItems/the redux store.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're mutating your state.  You're making a shallow copy of the top-level state in that slice reducer, but you aren't making copies of all the nested levels inside.  Then, your connected component is extracting `state.entriesData`, which hasn't changed by reference.  So, the `connect` wrapper component thinks that the state hasn't changed at all, and doesn't re-render your own component.

The [Redux docs page on "Immutable Update Patterns"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) specifically points this out as a common mistake.

If updating nested state immutably is too much of a pain, I'd suggest looking into the [`immer` immutable update library](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer/).  Also, our new [`redux-starter-kit` package](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-starter-kit) uses Immer internally to let you write simpler reducers.

Also, see my post [Idiomatic Redux: The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) for background and details on how `connect` works internally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also think you are mutating your state. The following is the `TOGGLE_TODO` case from reducer. I hope this code snippet will work for your code.

```
  case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
      if (index === action.index) {
        return Object.assign({}, todo, {
          completed: !todo.completed
        })
      }
      return todo
    })
  })
```

So, in your case if id matches then update is with `action.vote`. Also read about deep and shallow object copies.

Comment: Thnks for the code snippet! My issue was that I was shallow cloning using Object.assign when I should have been deep cloning. I'm not sure if the code snippet you posted takes that into account., but I don't think it does.

Comment: this should be accepted answer, parse(stringify)) is rather expensive operation if object is too big.

Answer (score 0):

markerikson was right, but I am posting the specific answer that helped me, here.

The problem was that I was trying to update an array inside of an object (entriesData being the object and entriesData.data being the array), using the normal method of Object.assign({}, state, {}) when I should have been using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)). I had to read Mozilla's explanation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to understand what was going on. I saw the JSON.parse solution before, but I didn't really understand shallow and deep cloning, and, whatever shallow cloning was, I didn't think I was guilty of it. Turns out, I was.

Here's my updated reducer that works perfectly.

```
case ContestActionTypes.HANDLE_VOTE:
  const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
  if (newState.entriesData) {
    const index = newState.entriesData.data.findIndex(x => x.id === action.entry.id)
    newState.entriesData.data[index].VotesCount = action.vote;
  } else {
    newState.entry.VotesCount = action.vote;
  }

  return newState;
```